# appending content in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which I populate with data and I want to insert other rows to that table, under the element that was clicked dynamically. I have an array of json objects called rows and when I click on a row it should fetch an array of json objects called campaigns.

This is my html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="toggleCollapse(row.id)">{{ row.name }}</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{ row.clicks }}</td>
    </tr>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="clicked">
    <tr ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;">{{ campaign.name}}</a> 
        </td>
        <td>{{ campaign.clicks }}</td>
    </tr>
    </script>
</tbody>
```

This is my function:

```
$scope.toggleCollapse = function(id) {
    var campaignId = id;
    if (campaignId === $scope.selectedRow) {
        $scope.selectedRow = null;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedRow = campaignId;
        $scope.ads.push({
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "TestName",
            "clicks" : 400
        })
        // append template here 
    }

};
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need javascript:void; in angular.  They have an 'a' directive which does that https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a seperate template, just put your  straight in.  If there is nothing in campaigns array, there will be 0 campaign s.